Functional equation $f(f(x)+y)+ xf(y) = f(xy+y)+ f(x)$
"Determine all functions $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ satisfying:
$f(f(x)+y)+ xf(y) = f(xy+y)+ f(x)$
For all positve reals x and y."
I tried some values for $x$ and $y$ such as $(y,x),(x,x),(1,x)$ and $(x,1)$ but did not find anything interesting. Any hints as how to continue?

You can try with simple functions, such as $f(x)=x$. It turns out that it satisfies the equation. To show that it is the unique, I would try with x=0 and y=0...

Might be excluded though to try $0$ by the domain, some people consider $\mathbb R^+=[0,+\infty)$ and others $(0,+\infty)$.

Generally in this kind of functional equation the solve consists in eliminating the composed $f$ i.e. $f(f(x)+y)$ by replacing $y$ by some clever expression containing $f(x)$ and after substitution it remains an equation without composition. But finding such $y$ is never trivial...

What contest is this from?

Here's my starting point:
Try $y = \frac{f(x)}{x}$, then
$$f \left(f(x) + \frac{f(x)}{x} \right) + x f \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right) = f \left(f(x) + \frac{f(x)}{x}\right) + f(x)$$
$$f \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
And in particular, setting $x = 1$ and $x = f(1)$, $$f \left(f(1)\right) = f(1)$$
$$f \left(\frac{f(f(1))}{f(1)}\right) = \frac{f(f(1))}{f(1)}$$
$$f(1) = 1$$

Your starting point was good but you went too far with trying x=1. You had already solved the problem: f(y) = y.

But that only holds for $y$ such that $\exists x$, with $f(x) = y$. i.e. everywhere in the image of $f$ is itself a fixed point. but that doesn't immediately imply the whole of $f$ is fixed. and if $f(y) = y$ is the solution, then $f(x)/x = 1$ for all $x$ which reduces that line to only saying that $f(1) = 1$

An example function would be $f(100) = 1$ and $f(x) = x$ everywhere else. it satisfies $f\left( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ but doesn't satisfy the original equation at $x=99, y=1$

Some ideas, but far from a solve...
Let set $Eq(x,y)=f(f(x)+y)+xf(y)-f(xy+y)-f(x)=0$
Assuming $f$ is defined in $0$ let set $a=f(0)$
$Eq(0,y)=f(a+y)+0-f(y)-a\implies f(x+a)=f(x)+a$
If $a \neq 0$ then $f(x)=x+P(x)$ where $P$ is periodic of period $P(0)=a$
Note $\begin{cases}f(0)=P(0)=a\\f(a)=a+P(a)=a+P(0)=2a\end{cases}$
But $Eq(a,0)=f(f(a))+af(0)-f(0)-f(a)=f(2a)+a^2-a-2a=3a+a^2-3a=a^2$
This implies $a=0$ contradiction, and $f(x)=x+P(x)$ with $P$ periodic is invalidated.
But we get that $f(0)=0$ is forced.
$Eq(x,0)\implies f(f(x))=f(x)$ and $f$ is the identity on its range (doesn't bring much for now...)
$\require{cancel}Eq(f(x),1)=\cancel{f(f(f(x))+1)}+f(x)f(1)-\cancel{f(f(x)+1)}-f(x)=f(x)(f(1)-1)$
Since $f=0$ is a trivial solution, let's get interested in non-null functions, in this case $f(1)=1$

And that's all I got so far... I hoped to prove $f(n)=n$ so if assuming continuity then $f$ range is whole $\mathbb R^+$ and from previously then $f(x)=x$, but I didn't manage to prove that on the integers, even $f(2)$ seems out of reach.
To summarize if $f$ defined in zero then $f$ is either identically null or $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(f(x))=f(x)$
If we do not assume $f$ defined in zero, I have even less clues...
